# .Net 4.8 webform httpcookie not updating on prod server

Tags: vb.net, webforms, httpcookie

We store user preferences in an httpcookie and they have worked for a long time. Recently they stopped working as expected on the production servers. They still work as expected locally and on the TEST servers.

On production the user selects an item/preference for the first and it is stored correctly in the cookie. Then the user comes back later and changes their selection and it should overwrite/update that same cookie. It will not update that value. In TEST it updates correctly every time.

```
Public Shared Sub PersistFilterId(ByRef pg As Page, ByVal filterId As String, ByVal pageType As RequestPageType)

    Dim ck As HttpCookie = pg.Request.Cookies("UserPreferenceCookie")

    If ck Is Nothing Then
        ck = New HttpCookie("UserPreferenceCookie")
    End If
      
    ck("FilterId") = filterId
    ck("operatorId") = GetOperatorId()
    ck.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)
    pg.Response.Cookies.Set(ck)
End Sub
```